# Truncated display of hour in R

Tags: r

I would like to create a vector of characters that will display all the possible Hours/Minutes of the day.

Hence, I would like to create a vector that looks like this

```
hours_mins = c("0:00",  "0:01",....,"5:09",  "5:10",  "5:11",  "5:12",  "5:14",  "5:15",..., "23:58", "23:59" )
```

However, my problem in creating this vector is that the hour displayed in `hours_mins` is not in the regular format, i.e. `00:00`, or `05:09`. Hence, how do I create a vector such as `hours_mins` with truncated display of the hour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a **base R** solution:

```
sub("^0","", strftime(as.POSIXct("00:00", format="%H:%M")+seq(0,86380,by=60), format="%H:%M") )
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```r
paste(rep(0:23, each = 60), rep(sprintf("%02d", 0:59), 24), sep = ":")

#>    [1] "0:00"  "0:01"  "0:02"  "0:03"  "0:04"  "0:05"  "0:06"  "0:07"  "0:08" 
#>   [10] "0:09"  "0:10"  "0:11"  "0:12"  "0:13"  "0:14"  "0:15"  "0:16"  "0:17" 
#>   [19] "0:18"  "0:19"  "0:20"  "0:21"  "0:22"  "0:23"  "0:24"  "0:25"  "0:26" 
#>   [28] "0:27"  "0:28"  "0:29"  "0:30"  "0:31"  "0:32"  "0:33"  "0:34"  "0:35" 
#>   [37] "0:36"  "0:37"  "0:38"  "0:39"  "0:40"  "0:41"  "0:42"  "0:43"  "0:44" 
#>   [46] "0:45"  "0:46"  "0:47"  "0:48"  "0:49"  "0:50"  "0:51"  "0:52"  "0:53" 
#>   [55] "0:54"  "0:55"  "0:56"  "0:57"  "0:58"  "0:59"  "1:00"  "1:01"  "1:02" 
#>   [64] "1:03"  "1:04"  "1:05"  "1:06"  "1:07"  "1:08"  "1:09"  "1:10"  "1:11" 
#>   [73] "1:12"  "1:13"  "1:14"  "1:15"  "1:16"  "1:17"  "1:18"  "1:19"  "1:20" 
#>   [82] "1:21"  "1:22"  "1:23"  "1:24"  "1:25"  "1:26"  "1:27"  "1:28"  "1:29" 
#>   [91] "1:30"  "1:31"  "1:32"  "1:33"  "1:34"  "1:35"  "1:36"  "1:37"  "1:38" 
#>  [100] "1:39"  "1:40"  "1:41"  "1:42"  "1:43"  "1:44"  "1:45"  "1:46"  "1:47" 
#>  [109] "1:48"  "1:49"  "1:50"  "1:51"  "1:52"  "1:53"  "1:54"  "1:55"  "1:56" 
#>  [118] "1:57"  "1:58"  "1:59"  "2:00"  "2:01"  "2:02"  "2:03"  "2:04"  "2:05" 
#>  [127] "2:06"  "2:07"  "2:08"  "2:09"  "2:10"  "2:11"  "2:12"  "2:13"  "2:14" 
#>  [136] "2:15"  "2:16"  "2:17"  "2:18"  "2:19"  "2:20"  "2:21"  "2:22"  "2:23" 
#>  [145] "2:24"  "2:25"  "2:26"  "2:27"  "2:28"  "2:29"  "2:30"  "2:31"  "2:32" 
#>  [154] "2:33"  "2:34"  "2:35"  "2:36"  "2:37"  "2:38"  "2:39"  "2:40"  "2:41" 
#>  [163] "2:42"  "2:43"  "2:44"  "2:45"  "2:46"  "2:47"  "2:48"  "2:49"  "2:50" 
#>  [172] "2:51"  "2:52"  "2:53"  "2:54"  "2:55"  "2:56"  "2:57"  "2:58"  "2:59" 
#>  [181] "3:00"  "3:01"  "3:02"  "3:03"  "3:04"  "3:05"  "3:06"  "3:07"  "3:08" 
#>  [190] "3:09"  "3:10"  "3:11"  "3:12"  "3:13"  "3:14"  "3:15"  "3:16"  "3:17" 
#>  [199] "3:18"  "3:19"  "3:20"  "3:21"  "3:22"  "3:23"  "3:24"  "3:25"  "3:26" 
#>  [208] "3:27"  "3:28"  "3:29"  "3:30"  "3:31"  "3:32"  "3:33"  "3:34"  "3:35" 
#>  [217] "3:36"  "3:37"  "3:38"  "3:39"  "3:40"  "3:41"  "3:42"  "3:43"  "3:44" 
#>  [226] "3:45"  "3:46"  "3:47"  "3:48"  "3:49"  "3:50"  "3:51"  "3:52"  "3:53" 
#>  [235] "3:54"  "3:55"  "3:56"  "3:57"  "3:58"  "3:59"  "4:00"  "4:01"  "4:02" 
#>  [244] "4:03"  "4:04"  "4:05"  "4:06"  "4:07"  "4:08"  "4:09"  "4:10"  "4:11" 
#>  [253] "4:12"  "4:13"  "4:14"  "4:15"  "4:16"  "4:17"  "4:18"  "4:19"  "4:20" 
#>  [262] "4:21"  "4:22"  "4:23"  "4:24"  "4:25"  "4:26"  "4:27"  "4:28"  "4:29" 
#>  [271] "4:30"  "4:31"  "4:32"  "4:33"  "4:34"  "4:35"  "4:36"  "4:37"  "4:38" 
#>  [280] "4:39"  "4:40"  "4:41"  "4:42"  "4:43"  "4:44"  "4:45"  "4:46"  "4:47" 
#>  [289] "4:48"  "4:49"  "4:50"  "4:51"  "4:52"  "4:53"  "4:54"  "4:55"  "4:56" 
#>  [298] "4:57"  "4:58"  "4:59"  "5:00"  "5:01"  "5:02"  "5:03"  "5:04"  "5:05" 
#>  [307] "5:06"  "5:07"  "5:08"  "5:09"  "5:10"  "5:11"  "5:12"  "5:13"  "5:14" 
#>  [316] "5:15"  "5:16"  "5:17"  "5:18"  "5:19"  "5:20"  "5:21"  "5:22"  "5:23" 
#>  [325] "5:24"  "5:25"  "5:26"  "5:27"  "5:28"  "5:29"  "5:30"  "5:31"  "5:32" 
#>  [334] "5:33"  "5:34"  "5:35"  "5:36"  "5:37"  "5:38"  "5:39"  "5:40"  "5:41" 
#>  [343] "5:42"  "5:43"  "5:44"  "5:45"  "5:46"  "5:47"  "5:48"  "5:49"  "5:50" 
#>  [352] "5:51"  "5:52"  "5:53"  "5:54"  "5:55"  "5:56"  "5:57"  "5:58"  "5:59" 
#>  [361] "6:00"  "6:01"  "6:02"  "6:03"  "6:04"  "6:05"  "6:06"  "6:07"  "6:08" 
#>  [370] "6:09"  "6:10"  "6:11"  "6:12"  "6:13"  "6:14"  "6:15"  "6:16"  "6:17" 
#>  [379] "6:18"  "6:19"  "6:20"  "6:21"  "6:22"  "6:23"  "6:24"  "6:25"  "6:26" 
#>  [388] "6:27"  "6:28"  "6:29"  "6:30"  "6:31"  "6:32"  "6:33"  "6:34"  "6:35" 
#>  [397] "6:36"  "6:37"  "6:38"  "6:39"  "6:40"  "6:41"  "6:42"  "6:43"  "6:44" 
#>  [406] "6:45"  "6:46"  "6:47"  "6:48"  "6:49"  "6:50"  "6:51"  "6:52"  "6:53" 
#>  [415] "6:54"  "6:55"  "6:56"  "6:57"  "6:58"  "6:59"  "7:00"  "7:01"  "7:02" 
#>  [424] "7:03"  "7:04"  "7:05"  "7:06"  "7:07"  "7:08"  "7:09"  "7:10"  "7:11" 
#>  [433] "7:12"  "7:13"  "7:14"  "7:15"  "7:16"  "7:17"  "7:18"  "7:19"  "7:20" 
#>  [442] "7:21"  "7:22"  "7:23"  "7:24"  "7:25"  "7:26"  "7:27"  "7:28"  "7:29" 
#>  [451] "7:30"  "7:31"  "7:32"  "7:33"  "7:34"  "7:35"  "7:36"  "7:37"  "7:38" 
#>  [460] "7:39"  "7:40"  "7:41"  "7:42"  "7:43"  "7:44"  "7:45"  "7:46"  "7:47" 
#>  [469] "7:48"  "7:49"  "7:50"  "7:51"  "7:52"  "7:53"  "7:54"  "7:55"  "7:56" 
#>  [478] "7:57"  "7:58"  "7:59"  "8:00"  "8:01"  "8:02"  "8:03"  "8:04"  "8:05" 
#>  [487] "8:06"  "8:07"  "8:08"  "8:09"  "8:10"  "8:11"  "8:12"  "8:13"  "8:14" 
#>  [496] "8:15"  "8:16"  "8:17"  "8:18"  "8:19"  "8:20"  "8:21"  "8:22"  "8:23" 
#>  [505] "8:24"  "8:25"  "8:26"  "8:27"  "8:28"  "8:29"  "8:30"  "8:31"  "8:32" 
#>  [514] "8:33"  "8:34"  "8:35"  "8:36"  "8:37"  "8:38"  "8:39"  "8:40"  "8:41" 
#>  [523] "8:42"  "8:43"  "8:44"  "8:45"  "8:46"  "8:47"  "8:48"  "8:49"  "8:50" 
#>  [532] "8:51"  "8:52"  "8:53"  "8:54"  "8:55"  "8:56"  "8:57"  "8:58"  "8:59" 
#>  [541] "9:00"  "9:01"  "9:02"  "9:03"  "9:04"  "9:05"  "9:06"  "9:07"  "9:08" 
#>  [550] "9:09"  "9:10"  "9:11"  "9:12"  "9:13"  "9:14"  "9:15"  "9:16"  "9:17" 
#>  [559] "9:18"  "9:19"  "9:20"  "9:21"  "9:22"  "9:23"  "9:24"  "9:25"  "9:26" 
#>  [568] "9:27"  "9:28"  "9:29"  "9:30"  "9:31"  "9:32"  "9:33"  "9:34"  "9:35" 
#>  [577] "9:36"  "9:37"  "9:38"  "9:39"  "9:40"  "9:41"  "9:42"  "9:43"  "9:44" 
#>  [586] "9:45"  "9:46"  "9:47"  "9:48"  "9:49"  "9:50"  "9:51"  "9:52"  "9:53" 
#>  [595] "9:54"  "9:55"  "9:56"  "9:57"  "9:58"  "9:59"  "10:00" "10:01" "10:02"
#>  [604] "10:03" "10:04" "10:05" "10:06" "10:07" "10:08" "10:09" "10:10" "10:11"
#>  [613] "10:12" "10:13" "10:14" "10:15" "10:16" "10:17" "10:18" "10:19" "10:20"
#>  [622] "10:21" "10:22" "10:23" "10:24" "10:25" "10:26" "10:27" "10:28" "10:29"
#>  [631] "10:30" "10:31" "10:32" "10:33" "10:34" "10:35" "10:36" "10:37" "10:38"
#>  [640] "10:39" "10:40" "10:41" "10:42" "10:43" "10:44" "10:45" "10:46" "10:47"
#>  [649] "10:48" "10:49" "10:50" "10:51" "10:52" "10:53" "10:54" "10:55" "10:56"
#>  [658] "10:57" "10:58" "10:59" "11:00" "11:01" "11:02" "11:03" "11:04" "11:05"
#>  [667] "11:06" "11:07" "11:08" "11:09" "11:10" "11:11" "11:12" "11:13" "11:14"
#>  [676] "11:15" "11:16" "11:17" "11:18" "11:19" "11:20" "11:21" "11:22" "11:23"
#>  [685] "11:24" "11:25" "11:26" "11:27" "11:28" "11:29" "11:30" "11:31" "11:32"
#>  [694] "11:33" "11:34" "11:35" "11:36" "11:37" "11:38" "11:39" "11:40" "11:41"
#>  [703] "11:42" "11:43" "11:44" "11:45" "11:46" "11:47" "11:48" "11:49" "11:50"
#>  [712] "11:51" "11:52" "11:53" "11:54" "11:55" "11:56" "11:57" "11:58" "11:59"
#>  [721] "12:00" "12:01" "12:02" "12:03" "12:04" "12:05" "12:06" "12:07" "12:08"
#>  [730] "12:09" "12:10" "12:11" "12:12" "12:13" "12:14" "12:15" "12:16" "12:17"
#>  [739] "12:18" "12:19" "12:20" "12:21" "12:22" "12:23" "12:24" "12:25" "12:26"
#>  [748] "12:27" "12:28" "12:29" "12:30" "12:31" "12:32" "12:33" "12:34" "12:35"
#>  [757] "12:36" "12:37" "12:38" "12:39" "12:40" "12:41" "12:42" "12:43" "12:44"
#>  [766] "12:45" "12:46" "12:47" "12:48" "12:49" "12:50" "12:51" "12:52" "12:53"
#>  [775] "12:54" "12:55" "12:56" "12:57" "12:58" "12:59" "13:00" "13:01" "13:02"
#>  [784] "13:03" "13:04" "13:05" "13:06" "13:07" "13:08" "13:09" "13:10" "13:11"
#>  [793] "13:12" "13:13" "13:14" "13:15" "13:16" "13:17" "13:18" "13:19" "13:20"
#>  [802] "13:21" "13:22" "13:23" "13:24" "13:25" "13:26" "13:27" "13:28" "13:29"
#>  [811] "13:30" "13:31" "13:32" "13:33" "13:34" "13:35" "13:36" "13:37" "13:38"
#>  [820] "13:39" "13:40" "13:41" "13:42" "13:43" "13:44" "13:45" "13:46" "13:47"
#>  [829] "13:48" "13:49" "13:50" "13:51" "13:52" "13:53" "13:54" "13:55" "13:56"
#>  [838] "13:57" "13:58" "13:59" "14:00" "14:01" "14:02" "14:03" "14:04" "14:05"
#>  [847] "14:06" "14:07" "14:08" "14:09" "14:10" "14:11" "14:12" "14:13" "14:14"
#>  [856] "14:15" "14:16" "14:17" "14:18" "14:19" "14:20" "14:21" "14:22" "14:23"
#>  [865] "14:24" "14:25" "14:26" "14:27" "14:28" "14:29" "14:30" "14:31" "14:32"
#>  [874] "14:33" "14:34" "14:35" "14:36" "14:37" "14:38" "14:39" "14:40" "14:41"
#>  [883] "14:42" "14:43" "14:44" "14:45" "14:46" "14:47" "14:48" "14:49" "14:50"
#>  [892] "14:51" "14:52" "14:53" "14:54" "14:55" "14:56" "14:57" "14:58" "14:59"
#>  [901] "15:00" "15:01" "15:02" "15:03" "15:04" "15:05" "15:06" "15:07" "15:08"
#>  [910] "15:09" "15:10" "15:11" "15:12" "15:13" "15:14" "15:15" "15:16" "15:17"
#>  [919] "15:18" "15:19" "15:20" "15:21" "15:22" "15:23" "15:24" "15:25" "15:26"
#>  [928] "15:27" "15:28" "15:29" "15:30" "15:31" "15:32" "15:33" "15:34" "15:35"
#>  [937] "15:36" "15:37" "15:38" "15:39" "15:40" "15:41" "15:42" "15:43" "15:44"
#>  [946] "15:45" "15:46" "15:47" "15:48" "15:49" "15:50" "15:51" "15:52" "15:53"
#>  [955] "15:54" "15:55" "15:56" "15:57" "15:58" "15:59" "16:00" "16:01" "16:02"
#>  [964] "16:03" "16:04" "16:05" "16:06" "16:07" "16:08" "16:09" "16:10" "16:11"
#>  [973] "16:12" "16:13" "16:14" "16:15" "16:16" "16:17" "16:18" "16:19" "16:20"
#>  [982] "16:21" "16:22" "16:23" "16:24" "16:25" "16:26" "16:27" "16:28" "16:29"
#>  [991] "16:30" "16:31" "16:32" "16:33" "16:34" "16:35" "16:36" "16:37" "16:38"
#> [1000] "16:39" "16:40" "16:41" "16:42" "16:43" "16:44" "16:45" "16:46" "16:47"
#> [1009] "16:48" "16:49" "16:50" "16:51" "16:52" "16:53" "16:54" "16:55" "16:56"
#> [1018] "16:57" "16:58" "16:59" "17:00" "17:01" "17:02" "17:03" "17:04" "17:05"
#> [1027] "17:06" "17:07" "17:08" "17:09" "17:10" "17:11" "17:12" "17:13" "17:14"
#> [1036] "17:15" "17:16" "17:17" "17:18" "17:19" "17:20" "17:21" "17:22" "17:23"
#> [1045] "17:24" "17:25" "17:26" "17:27" "17:28" "17:29" "17:30" "17:31" "17:32"
#> [1054] "17:33" "17:34" "17:35" "17:36" "17:37" "17:38" "17:39" "17:40" "17:41"
#> [1063] "17:42" "17:43" "17:44" "17:45" "17:46" "17:47" "17:48" "17:49" "17:50"
#> [1072] "17:51" "17:52" "17:53" "17:54" "17:55" "17:56" "17:57" "17:58" "17:59"
#> [1081] "18:00" "18:01" "18:02" "18:03" "18:04" "18:05" "18:06" "18:07" "18:08"
#> [1090] "18:09" "18:10" "18:11" "18:12" "18:13" "18:14" "18:15" "18:16" "18:17"
#> [1099] "18:18" "18:19" "18:20" "18:21" "18:22" "18:23" "18:24" "18:25" "18:26"
#> [1108] "18:27" "18:28" "18:29" "18:30" "18:31" "18:32" "18:33" "18:34" "18:35"
#> [1117] "18:36" "18:37" "18:38" "18:39" "18:40" "18:41" "18:42" "18:43" "18:44"
#> [1126] "18:45" "18:46" "18:47" "18:48" "18:49" "18:50" "18:51" "18:52" "18:53"
#> [1135] "18:54" "18:55" "18:56" "18:57" "18:58" "18:59" "19:00" "19:01" "19:02"
#> [1144] "19:03" "19:04" "19:05" "19:06" "19:07" "19:08" "19:09" "19:10" "19:11"
#> [1153] "19:12" "19:13" "19:14" "19:15" "19:16" "19:17" "19:18" "19:19" "19:20"
#> [1162] "19:21" "19:22" "19:23" "19:24" "19:25" "19:26" "19:27" "19:28" "19:29"
#> [1171] "19:30" "19:31" "19:32" "19:33" "19:34" "19:35" "19:36" "19:37" "19:38"
#> [1180] "19:39" "19:40" "19:41" "19:42" "19:43" "19:44" "19:45" "19:46" "19:47"
#> [1189] "19:48" "19:49" "19:50" "19:51" "19:52" "19:53" "19:54" "19:55" "19:56"
#> [1198] "19:57" "19:58" "19:59" "20:00" "20:01" "20:02" "20:03" "20:04" "20:05"
#> [1207] "20:06" "20:07" "20:08" "20:09" "20:10" "20:11" "20:12" "20:13" "20:14"
#> [1216] "20:15" "20:16" "20:17" "20:18" "20:19" "20:20" "20:21" "20:22" "20:23"
#> [1225] "20:24" "20:25" "20:26" "20:27" "20:28" "20:29" "20:30" "20:31" "20:32"
#> [1234] "20:33" "20:34" "20:35" "20:36" "20:37" "20:38" "20:39" "20:40" "20:41"
#> [1243] "20:42" "20:43" "20:44" "20:45" "20:46" "20:47" "20:48" "20:49" "20:50"
#> [1252] "20:51" "20:52" "20:53" "20:54" "20:55" "20:56" "20:57" "20:58" "20:59"
#> [1261] "21:00" "21:01" "21:02" "21:03" "21:04" "21:05" "21:06" "21:07" "21:08"
#> [1270] "21:09" "21:10" "21:11" "21:12" "21:13" "21:14" "21:15" "21:16" "21:17"
#> [1279] "21:18" "21:19" "21:20" "21:21" "21:22" "21:23" "21:24" "21:25" "21:26"
#> [1288] "21:27" "21:28" "21:29" "21:30" "21:31" "21:32" "21:33" "21:34" "21:35"
#> [1297] "21:36" "21:37" "21:38" "21:39" "21:40" "21:41" "21:42" "21:43" "21:44"
#> [1306] "21:45" "21:46" "21:47" "21:48" "21:49" "21:50" "21:51" "21:52" "21:53"
#> [1315] "21:54" "21:55" "21:56" "21:57" "21:58" "21:59" "22:00" "22:01" "22:02"
#> [1324] "22:03" "22:04" "22:05" "22:06" "22:07" "22:08" "22:09" "22:10" "22:11"
#> [1333] "22:12" "22:13" "22:14" "22:15" "22:16" "22:17" "22:18" "22:19" "22:20"
#> [1342] "22:21" "22:22" "22:23" "22:24" "22:25" "22:26" "22:27" "22:28" "22:29"
#> [1351] "22:30" "22:31" "22:32" "22:33" "22:34" "22:35" "22:36" "22:37" "22:38"
#> [1360] "22:39" "22:40" "22:41" "22:42" "22:43" "22:44" "22:45" "22:46" "22:47"
#> [1369] "22:48" "22:49" "22:50" "22:51" "22:52" "22:53" "22:54" "22:55" "22:56"
#> [1378] "22:57" "22:58" "22:59" "23:00" "23:01" "23:02" "23:03" "23:04" "23:05"
#> [1387] "23:06" "23:07" "23:08" "23:09" "23:10" "23:11" "23:12" "23:13" "23:14"
#> [1396] "23:15" "23:16" "23:17" "23:18" "23:19" "23:20" "23:21" "23:22" "23:23"
#> [1405] "23:24" "23:25" "23:26" "23:27" "23:28" "23:29" "23:30" "23:31" "23:32"
#> [1414] "23:33" "23:34" "23:35" "23:36" "23:37" "23:38" "23:39" "23:40" "23:41"
#> [1423] "23:42" "23:43" "23:44" "23:45" "23:46" "23:47" "23:48" "23:49" "23:50"
#> [1432] "23:51" "23:52" "23:53" "23:54" "23:55" "23:56" "23:57" "23:58" "23:59"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

A regex solution with `sub` and backreference `\\1`:

```
sub("^(\\d)(?=:)", "0\\1", hours_mins, perl = TRUE)
 [1] "00:00" "00:01" "05:09" "05:10" "05:11" "05:12" "05:14" "05:15" "23:58" "23:59"
```

Data:

```
hours_mins <- c("0:00",  "0:01","5:09",  "5:10",  "5:11",  "5:12",  "5:14",  "5:15","23:58", "23:59")
```